# iTunes Connect unable to submit build

Tags: xcode6, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit my app to the App Store via iTunes Connect. Everything is fine until I tried to upload the binary. On Xcode 6, I archived and validated my app, then pressed submit, of which it said submitted successfully. But in my iTunesConnect portal, the submitted build isn't on there. It is not under versions or prerelease. I have waited for over an hour if it is a waiting issue. Regardless, the uploaded build would not show up!